# Use a CSS transformation on an entire page including fixed backgrounds (in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I've made a script that re-sizes my website with some ratio: 'rat'. I do a scale but that scale creates white margins so I transform the entire html page and I sent it to origin in the coordinates 0 , 0.

```
document.documentElement.style.transform = "scale(" + rat + ")";
document.documentElement.style.width = 100 / rat + "%";
document.documentElement.style.transformOrigin = '0 0';
```

The problem I have is that some background images with the following property do not transform:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Everytime I transform my html page the background images with `background-attachment: fixed;` don't transform.

You can check what I'm talking about in my portfolio here:

http://testedesignfranjas.tumblr.com/

Open the site in chrome and in FIREFOX and see the differences.
The issue is in Firefox.

*sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are you sure that the code above is executed? Is it in placed in the head of your website, and if not, is it invoked somewhere within?

Comment: I'm sure, but its only executed on firefox, because on chrome I use another script I made that I check user screen width and i use this instead:

            document.documentElement.style.zoom = rat + "%";

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood it very well, but have you tried adding background-size: 100% auto? to #img1, #img2 and others...

Comment: Do your script executes when document is ready, or does it also on resize?

Comment: Try adding a `traslateZ(1px)` to the transform and see if that fixes anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a partial answer. Firefox doesn't always treat nested, fixed elements correctly when using a transform. Instead of using background-attachment, make the div with the image position:fixed. The second div is relative or static, so it will overlay the first div.

```
<body onload="scaleAll(0.8)">
  <div id="img1">I have a background image, am scaled and am fixed.</div>
  <div id="outer">
     I have content and am scaled.
  </div>
</body>
```

I have moved the image outside the div and set img1 to position:fixed. Do the scaling individually, once for img1 and once for the outer div that has the content.

```
<script>
function scale(rat, container) {
    var element = document.getElementById(container);
    element.style.transform = 'scale(' + rat + ')';
    element.style.transformOrigin = '0 0';
}   

function scaleAll(rat) {
    scale(rat, "outer");
    scale(rat, "img1");
}
</script>
```

The style uses position:fixed for the img1 and relative for the outer.

```
<style>
    div#outer { 
        position: relative;
        height: 900px;
        width: 900px;
    }
    #img1 {
        position: fixed;
        background: url("image.png") no-repeat;
        width: 796px;
        height: 397px;
    }
</style>
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/downeyt/tu21nmyk/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to remove the "fixed" attribute when you scale document

```
$("img").each(function() {
$(this).css("background-attachment","");
});
```